# How do I rotate the GPUImageView image clockwise 90 degrees when in Landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage to create an photo app, the app in question is always in Landscape mode. I was wondering how I go about rotating the displayed image by 90 degrees clockwise because currently it is not in the correct orientation.

I have tried to change the following line but it throws out the crop.

```
 _stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

This is the code I am using so far.

```
[_stillCamera stopCameraCapture];

if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width == 667){

    if(cameraPosition == 1){

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    }else {

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

    }

}
else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width == 568){

    if(cameraPosition == 1){

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    }else {

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

    }

} else{

    if(cameraPosition == 1){

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    }else {

        _stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];

    }

}

_stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

_cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.125f, 1.f, .75f)];


self.lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LondonTown2.png"]];
[self.lookupImageSource processImage];

self.filterLookup = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[self.lookupImageSource addTarget:self.filterLookup atTextureLocation:1];



[_stillCamera addTarget:self.filterLookup];
[self.filterLookup addTarget:_cropFilter];








[_filterViewViewFinder setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill];

//[_stillCamera addTarget:_cropFilter];
//[_cropFilter addTarget:_filter];

[_cropFilter addTarget:_filterView];
[_cropFilter addTarget:_filterViewViewFinder];

[_stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate your `GPUImageView` image by below code.

```
[self.filterLookup setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotateRight atIndex:0];
```

And different `InputRotation` modes are below.

```
kGPUImageNoRotation, 
kGPUImageRotateLeft, 
kGPUImageRotateRight,
kGPUImageFlipVertical, 
kGPUImageFlipHorizonal,
kGPUImageRotateRightFlipVertical,
kGPUImageRotateRightFlipHorizontal,
kGPUImageRotate180
```

Hope this helps.